# C# Windows Phone 8.1 Inconsistent Timer Issues with Periodic Timer

Tags: c#, flash, timer, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to get the background to flash a color indefinitely. I have something that's mostly working, but I noticed that the time interval between the color flashes are very inconsistent - sometimes very fast, other times it goes slowly.

IF I don't use the PeriodicTimer function call, the background flashes for approximately 1 second pretty consistently. But, the timer expires after about 1.5 - 2 minutes, which is not what I want. I'd like to know if there's a better way to implement this, rather than using two timers. Currently, I need the 2nd timer for the time delays between switching colors.

```
ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(elapsedHandle, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Elapsed Time Handler:

```
private void elapsedHandle(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
    {
        Timer flashTimer = new Timer(Callback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
```

Callback function:

```
    private void Callback(object state)
    {
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                // Your UI update code goes here!
                if (backgroundColorFill.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    backgroundWhiteFill.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    backgroundColorFill.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }

                else
                {
                    backgroundColorFill.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    backgroundWhiteFill.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                //flightImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                  
                //iconImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            );

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are syncing to the UI thread anyway, have you considered a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx)? You set the `Interval` to be 1 second and the `Tick` event to be your callback.

Comment: It worked! DispatcherTimer was actually the first thing I tried, since I had already implemented it in another project. But the first time I tried it, I didn't really know what I was doing. Thanks Peter!